# What Sims do I speak to in the Death of a Proxy: Proxy Election Time approach?

Tags: sims-medieval

I'm working on the 'annex all territories' goal and am on the quest Death of a Proxy. I have my Jacoban Priest trying to find a new candidate, and have spoken to a jester but don't have a second Sim with the 'this is your target' appearing anywhere. Meanwhile, my merchant has collected the cloth and crown and given them to a third(?) Sim who now is named "Candidate".

Has my priest bugged out? Is there any way to recover this playthrough without restarting from scratch?